# Is "%#x" equivalent to "0x%x" in the format string of printf family functions?

Tags: c, printf

Are these two function calls equivalent? ( Assuming that the type of variable `x` is `unsigned int`)

```
printf ("%#x\n", x);
printf ("0x%x\n", x);
```

And the following two function calls:

```
printf ("%#.8x\n", x);
printf ("0x%08x\n", x);
```

Why do some embedded programs prefers the latter one to the former one?

Comment: Do you have access to a C reference? That would be the first place to look.

Comment: Might be because for some fool reason `#` only works for *non-zero* inputs (ISO/IEC 9899:2011§7.21.6.1¶6). So if your value might be zero, `%#.8x` will (or may) display `00000000` rather than the `0x00000000` you would have hoped for. Alternatively, self-hosted implementations may not have the full suite of formatting specs, and better safe than sorry, why use `#` if you don't *need* to after all?

Answer (score 2):

From the C standard 7.9.16.1 para 6, on `#` in `fprintf`:

> The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’... For x (or X) conversion, a nonzero
> result has 0x (or 0X) prefixed to it.

So there you have it: `%#x` prefixes `0x` to any non-zero result. So it's the same as `0x%x` except when the result is zero.